# send a file objet to the backend

Tags: reactjs, api, object, post

I am trying to send a file object to the API. My code is as follow

```
const imagePreview = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
    setImg(e.target.files[0]);
    setPreview({file: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])});
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const request = {
      UserId: userId.id,
      data: input,
      post_img: img,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/post/createpost', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + userId.token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(request)
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // window.location.reload()
    })
  };
```

When I console.log(request) from the frontend I am getting the following:

```
{UserId: 1, data: "", post_img: File}
  UserId: 1
  data: ""
  post_img: File {name: "1590003577120.jpeg", lastModified: 1615470050830, lastModifiedDate: Thu 
    Mar 11 2021 13:40:50 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 5103, …}
```

So here post_img is not an empty object, if I was to console.log(req.body) from the backend this is what I'd get:

```
{ UserId: 1, data: '', post_img: {} }
```

The objet is now empty, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the file data will be in req.files not in req.body object.

```
const file = req.files.post_img;
console.log(file);
```